# Get the last timein of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem in my array. How can I get the lastest time from array? As you can see in my sample code

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-08-04 01:00:00
    [1] => 2015-08-03 16:00:00
    [2] => 2015-08-03 10:00:00
)
```

That is just a sample result of my list. It can change anytime. It depends on my setting. I tried to solve this, but don't have any idea to change the array. I want to get the

```
2015-08-04 01:00:00
```

Hoping for your help. I know only strtotime().

Comment: Do you mean first or last item in array? You say last but you say you want to see `2015-08-04 01:00:00` which is the first item.

Comment: sorry for not clearing my post. The value of array, it can change anytime. The value of array it might be switch into places, depends of my settings. I only want is the value from array. the end fo time from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your timestamps are formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss` you can use `max` to get latest time in the array

```
$latest = max($values);
print $latest;
```

Comment: thanks! wew max() is the right function in php. I'm looking for this. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `usort()` to sort date by ASC or DESC then get the last time. Example

```
$array = array(
    '2015-08-04 01:00:00',
    '2015-08-03 16:00:00',
    '2015-08-03 10:00:00',
);

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
});

$lastTime = end($array);

print $lastTime;
```